# Gsheets replacing value of cell based on another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I have 2 tables, the first has a list of acc numbers (column A) and Customer Name (column B). This list will have multiple entries of each customer. The problem is that this list is updated by multiple people who while gets the Acc number right they often mis-spell the customer name.

I have a second list that has the customer acc number and customer name spelt right.

What I want to do is take the customer name with the correct spelling from list 2 and replace the incorrect spelling in list 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the formula and copy/paste "values only" over WRONG names

`=ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup(A2:A,D2:E,2,0)))`

[copy/paste these "values only" over WRONG names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zx10R.png)

Answer (score 1):

As there are probably many ways you can spell coustomer's name incorrectly, it's very difficult to make autocorrect in spreadsheet. Also it may be dangerous.

What I suggest is to use data validation set based on a column with customer names in 'second list'.

Menu --> Data --> Data validation

[image]

This method allows manual input or choosing from dropdown list.
It also let's add new customers but it will trigger the warning